# Visio Web part data connection formatting issue format value in want $200M vs 200000000

Tags: excel, sharepoint, formatting, connection, visio

I have a Visio Web Part that has a data connection to an excel file with the value of 200,000,000. How do I get it to show as 200M without changing the excel file value or adding an other cell data connection value?

I've tried formatting Excel value to show differently, I've tried using various shapesheet fields, I've tried configuring the value various ways etc....

Comment: You could write a VBA sub to take the number from the Excel spreadsheet and return it as a formatted string - use modular arithmetic + `Select Case` to quickly set appropriate string format (since the `FormatCurrency()` settings probably aren't specific enough to meet your needs).

Comment: sounds interesting haven't used some of that before, but gives me ideas. Never thought to try formatting by VBA before. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about Web Parts, but if I understand you right, your issue is the value "displayed" in Visio.
Now modifiying display values in Visio is very easy. Instead of just displaying let's say prop.myval, use instead str(prop.myval / 100.000) & "M".

As for the implementation, instead of inserting the value of the prop field, insert a formula as described above.

Comment: I will give that a try Thank you!